# Character array is empty during second iteration of loop

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, arduino

I'm currently trying to learn C++ and the Arduino platform at the same time. That means that I do not have stl available to me.

The implementation of my code is at the bottom of the page, my Arduino loop invokes refresh consistently and my process flow goes from there. I receive the data and seemingly add it to my array correctly, but when I receive a second connection, the data property for my first connection is seemingly empty. Logs below:

```
15:42:53.153 -> Board setup complete
15:42:53.926 -> Received Short Range Data : Authorized Short Range Communicati
15:42:53.991 -> Data being returned from shortRangeListener::listen : Authorized Short Range Communicati
15:42:54.089 -> New Connection Instantiated : <Data:Authorized Short Range Communicati; LastEstablishedConnectionTime:898>
15:42:54.221 -> Short Range Connection received. Manging short range connections.
15:42:54.286 -> Hub::manageConnections invoked.
15:42:54.318 -> Connection established for <Data:Authorized Short Range Communicati; LastEstablishedConnectionTime:898>
15:42:54.418 -> Connections after adding latest 
15:42:54.452 -> <Data:Authorized Short Range Communicati; LastEstablishedConnectionTime:898>
15:42:55.245 -> Received Short Range Data : Authorized Short Range Communicati
15:42:55.311 -> Data being returned from shortRangeListener::listen : Authorized Short Range Communicati
15:42:55.409 -> New Connection Instantiated : <Data:Authorized Short Range Communicati; LastEstablishedConnectionTime:2217>
15:42:55.539 -> Short Range Connection received. Manging short range connections.
15:42:55.605 -> Hub::manageConnections invoked.
15:42:55.637 -> Current Connections:
15:42:55.637 -> <Data:; LastEstablishedConnectionTime:898>
```

I am hoping for help in understanding this behavior. I am currently working under the assumption that I am not handling the data variable that is returned from listen correctly. I BELIEVE I am returning a copy of the values held in my buffer, and that since I am dynamically allocating memory for the data value I should not be impacted by later iterations, but that is proving false.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Hub.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <RH_ASK.h>

// Short Range Listener
void ShortRangeListener::begin()
{
  Serial.println("Beginning Short Range Listener");

  driver.init();

  Serial.println("Short Range Listener began.");
}

char *ShortRangeListener::listen()
{
  if (driver.recv(buf, sizeof(buf)))
  {
    buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the buffer
    Serial.print("Received Short Range Data : ");
    Serial.println((char *)buf);

    char *data = new char[strlen((char *)buf) + 1];
    strcpy(data, (char *)buf);
    return data;
  }
  return nullptr;
}

// Connection
Connection::Connection()
{
  data = nullptr;
  lastEstablishedConnectionTime = 0;
}

void Connection::print(bool newLine = true)
{
  Serial.print("<Data:");
  Serial.print(data);
  Serial.print("; LastEstablishedConnectionTime:");
  Serial.print(lastEstablishedConnectionTime);
  Serial.print(">");

  if (newLine)
  {
    Serial.println();
  }
}

// Hub
Hub::Hub() : shortRangeConnections(new Connection[maxConnections])
{
}

void Hub::begin(const byte cePin, const byte csnPin, const byte longRangeAddress[5])
{
  Serial.println("Beginning Hub");

  shortRangeListener = new ShortRangeListener();
  shortRangeListener->begin();

  Serial.println("Hub has began.");
}

void Hub::refresh(long currentOrchestrationStartTime)
{
  Connection *shortRangeConnection = getConnection(shortRangeListener, currentOrchestrationStartTime);
  if (shortRangeConnection)
  {
    Serial.println("Short Range Connection received. Manging short range connections.");
    manageConnections(shortRangeConnection, shortRangeConnections, &numberOfShortRangeConnections, currentOrchestrationStartTime);
  }
}

Connection *Hub::getConnection(Listener *listener, long currentOrchestrationStartTime)
{
  char *data = listener->listen();
  if (data)
  {
    Connection *connection = new Connection();
    connection->data = new char[strlen(data) + 1];
    strcpy(connection->data, data);
    connection->lastEstablishedConnectionTime = currentOrchestrationStartTime;
    Serial.print("New Connection Instantiated : ");
    connection->print();
    return connection;
  }
  return nullptr;
}

void Hub::manageConnections(Connection *connection, Connection *connections, int *numberOfConnections, long currentOrchestrationStartTime)
{
  Serial.println("Hub::manageConnections invoked.");
  if (*numberOfConnections > 0)
  {
    Serial.println("Current Connections:");
    for (int i = 0; i < (*numberOfConnections); i++)
    {
      connections[i].print();
    }
  }

  if ((*numberOfConnections) >= maxConnections)
  {
    Serial.print("Max connections established. Connection ");
    Serial.print(connection->data);
    Serial.println(" cannot be added.");
    return;
  }

  connections[(*numberOfConnections)] = *connection;
  (*numberOfConnections)++;
  Serial.print("Connection established for ");
  connection->print();

  Serial.println("Connections after adding latest ");
  for (int i = 0; i < (*numberOfConnections); i++)
  {
    connections[i].print();
  }
}
```

I have worked with ChatGPT before coming here, and much of the terminating buffer and copy functionality stems from those suggestions.

Comment: Where does `buf` come from?  You really should avoid general purpose allocators like `new` or `malloc` on embedded platforms.  Where do you think `new` is getting memory from?  What happens if that memory runs out?  Without looking too hard for other issues, this is a classic [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: Also, `buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0';` is likely not doing what you expect either.  That puts a null terminator at the end of the buffer, not at the end of the string.

Comment: Recommendation: don't mention ChatGPT. Obviously if it provided a workable solution you wouldn't be asking this question. When the Wizard ask you to describe what you tried, it means the code you wrote, the tools you attempted to use, and the documentation you read and applied. It doesn't mean for you to say, "I prayed to the LLM gods that there'd be an easy answer."

Comment: I don't really understand why you say the standard library isn't available to you. It's C++. You can use the standard library with Arduino, and you'll write better code that way. There's _way_ too much pointer shenanigans going on here right now. You shouldn't really need any pointers at all.

Comment: Regarding your actual problem, your code is incomplete and requires a [mre]. Either debug it yourself, or post a proper example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: *I'm currently trying to learn C++ and the Arduino platform at the same time* -- Strike one.  C++ is one of the most difficult languages to learn out there.  Trying to squeeze in learning a framework at the same time trying to learn C++ will just lead you down the path of making simple mistakes that a C++ programmer who has spent a few weeks learning C++ wouldn't make.  *I have worked with ChatGPT before coming here* -- at the present time, ChatGPT and any AI is not going to teach C++ properly.  Again, for the reasons that C++ is just too complex a language to have a bot figure it out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 
I keep stepping back and taking C++ courses to try to understand my actual problems. I am explicitly using ChatGPT to supply my implementation and see if it can explain the behavior to me, not asking it to generate code for me. I'm honestly trying to understand what is happening, more than trying to find the fix. (The fix would be nice, but I am trying to learn and understand where I went wrong with my memory more than anything right now. I doubt this is the last issue I will face).

Comment: @paddy
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/24790/is-the-c-stl-fully-supported-on-arduino

This states that the STL library is not supported on Arduino. I have found other threads claiming the same.

Comment: Side note: the STL refers to the Standard Template Library, a hugely influential library from the 1990s that provided the ideological underpinnings for the Standardized C++ Standard Library in 1998 along with and more than a little of the basis for the implementations initial implementations. Bits of STL still live on in the C++ Standard Library and some folks still use STL when they are actually discussing the C++ Standard Library. Use a bit of caution here because they are different.

Comment: Learning C++ using Arduino does you a disservice. Arduino is more C-with-classes  than C++, so you aren't really learning C++. Second the tools available to you on the Arduino are generally inferior to the tools available on a PC where you can easily step through the code with a debugger and see exactly what your program does, profile, and get excellent diagnostic reports from sanitizers. When I develop for an embedded target, I first prove out the logic on a PC and then port the code to the Arduino.

Comment: Again, a full example is required. You have not shown the definitions of the classes you are implementing. One potential issue is that it looks like your `Connection` class does not follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/1553090). The line `connections[(*numberOfConnections)] = *connection;` _copies_ an object. This might not cause double deletion (your class doesn't even have a destructor), but you are still leaking the original object. Consider storing pointers in your connections array instead, or following the better advice already given in comments.